# Is it possible to have a Facebook app signup directly from an ad

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

If I have a Facebook app which I use for allowing sign in via Facebook on my site.
Is it possible to have a ‘sign up’ call-to-action on a Facebook ad that signs a user up to my app, then forwards them onto my website? The dev support pages talk a lot about changing labels on CTAs, but these are only labels. 
What I'd like is a 3 step process:
(1) User sees ad, clicks 'sign up' CTA
(2) User asked to grant permissions to my app
(3) User forwarded to my site, already logged in via Facebook.
I'm guessing there is a technical reason why this isn't possible - is it because the FB authentication needs to be initiated by the calling website? Thanks!

Comment: If you can specify an external URL as the CTA target(?), then you could just point it to a URL of your site, that itself automatically redirects to the login dialog. (But I’d consider this very bad UX – before I grant an app any permissions, I want to know what the app does, what it offers me, basically why it would be beneficial for me to use that app. If I just get the login dialog thrown in my face, I have none of this. IMHO it is always preferable to trigger login only when users explicitly request it.)

Comment: Agreed, this approach could be fairly ambitious as it assumes the ad has told the user enough about the site to warrant automatic signup.  That'd have to be a damn good ad, and a fairly trusting user.  I guess that's why there's no precedent?